# How to pass five sequences of images to tflite model in android

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I've tflite model which has input shape: (5,128,256,3) and have 3 classes.

**note: First dimension `5` is not batch size. If batch size is considered then it is (None, 5, 128, 256, 3)*

So now to test my model in android I want to feed it with 5 images.

So first I've created ByteBuffer and allocated sufficient storage and later converted it to FloatBuffer.

`val imageBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(5 * 256 * 128 * 3 * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer()`

I've read images, done all the necessary preprocessing and used `put` method of FloatBuffer to store it into `imageBuffer`.

Now when trying to run `interpreter.run(imageBuffer, output)` I'm getting error as shown below:

`tensorflow/lite/kernels/unpack.cc:67 data->num != input_shape->data[axis] (5 != 128)`

Comment: It is really hard to reproduce/answer your problem since there are limitations on the model information. Please consider creating minimal and reproducible steps as a format of CoLab if possible to get others' help.

Comment: @JaesungChung basically the model accepts five images not one. I'm afraid it can't be shared as colab notebook because it's an Android issue which I'm unable to make it work. In python everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

So I have solved the problem with simple resizing of the interpreter from

`interpreter.resize(5, 128, 256, 3)` -> `interpreter.resize(1, 5, 128, 256, 3)`

So that now `data->num = input_shape->data[axis]` which are
5 respectively.